# Adding extra CSS to the MasterPage - what is the sure shot way?

Tags: master-page

I have tried so many ways from different sites, including adding the css to the Scripts Library/Scripts. Addinbg the script directly in the Seattle MasterPage via Seattle .html
Tried to register it and got errors.

All I would love to do is be able to have the Master Page have the updated / overridden css info I have for the global left nav menu.
Unfortunately I don't know how to use delegations or crate something from Visual Studio to fix it.

Please pardon someone real hard to learn.
I just can't seem to get any scripts read of my master page.
They are uploaded, published, etc.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in

```
<head>
```

tag of html file of your master page you can provide your css link as below

```
<link href="/sites/SiteName/Style%20Library/CustomCSS/Customcss.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Eidt the master page in SharePoint Designer and add `SharePoint:CSSRegistration`. Example:

```
<SharePoint:CSSRegistration name= "<%$SPrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/Custom.css%>" runat="server"/>
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.cssregistration(v=office.14).aspx